# Python QGIS Processing of Shortest Path

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I would like to use python and execute the Shortest Path Processing using QGIS. But I would like to ask on how can I load the Vector Layer (endPointLayer ) in the END_POINT (params)?

The below is my python code

```
endPointLayer = QgsVectorLayer("c:\\allpoints.geojson","mygeojson","ogr")

params = { 
    'INPUT': 'c:\\road.shp',
    'STRATEGY': 0,
    'START_POINTS': '24750.776333512130805,42093.902984226690023 [EPSG:3414]',
    'END_POINT': endPointLayer,
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
}

output = processing.run("qgis:shortestpathpointtolayer", params)
```

My error message as below

```
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for END_POINTS: no value specified for parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint need to be a coordinate as the start point and not a QgsVectorLayer.
Get and points iterating over a QgsVectorLayer to get x and y coordinates for each feature.

```
points = iface.activeLayer()
for i in points.getFeatures():
    geom = i.geometry()
    print(geom.asPoint().x())
    print(geom.asPoint().y())
```